# NSColor sometimes mutating to NSColorWell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscolor

I have a class that handles a lot of defaults, here is how I initialize the defaults:

```
+ (void) initialize
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData* colorData= [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: [NSColor orangeColor]];
    NSDictionary* def= @{ @"colorKey" : colorData, ... };
    [defaults registerDefaults: def];
}
```

Then I make available one method for reading the default color and one method for setting it:

```
- (NSColor*) color
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData* colorData= [defaults objectForKey: colorKey];
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: colorData];
}

- (void) setColor: (NSColor*) color
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData* colorData= [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: color];
    [defaults setObject:colorData forKey: colorKey];
}
```

But if inside the color: method I print the color, sometimes it's of class NSColorWell and it creates troubles inside the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSColorWell` is an `NSControl` according to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorWell_Class/Reference/Reference.html, so it looks like that you are mistakenly calling `setColor:` with `NSColorWell` instance instead of `NSColor`.